# .net maui publishing android app fails due to issue during linking

Tags: .net-maui, .net-7.0

I have an .net maui application using .net 7 preview 2 that I want to publish for Android.

My publish command: `dotnet publish ${{env.UI_PROJECT_PATH}} -f net7.0-android -c Release`

This gives me this error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks\build\Microsoft.NET.ILLink.targets(86,5): error NETSDK1144: Optimizing assemblies for size failed. Optimization can be disabled by setting the PublishTrimmed property to false. [D:\a\MoneyFox\MoneyFox\src\MoneyFox.Ui\MoneyFox.Ui.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
ILLink : error IL1011: Failed to write 'obj\Release\net7.0-android\android-x64\linked\SkiaSharp.Views.Android.dll'. [D:\a\MoneyFox\MoneyFox\src\MoneyFox.Ui\MoneyFox.Ui.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
  Fatal error in IL Linker
  Unhandled exception. Mono.Linker.LinkerFatalErrorException: ILLink: error IL1011: Failed to write 'obj\Release\net7.0-android\android-x64\linked\SkiaSharp.Views.Android.dll'.
   ---> System.ArgumentException: Member 'System.Int32 SKCanvasView_ignorePixelScaling' is declared in another module and needs to be imported
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.LookupToken(IMetadataTokenProvider provider)
     at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeWriter.WriteOperand(Instruction instruction)
     at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeWriter.WriteInstructions()
     at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeWriter.WriteResolvedMethodBody(MethodDefinition method)
     at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeWriter.WriteMethodBody(MethodDefinition method)
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddMethod(MethodDefinition method)
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddMethods(TypeDefinition type)
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddType(TypeDefinition type)
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddTypes()
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildTypes()
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule()
     at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildMetadata()
     at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.<>c.<BuildMetadata>b__2_0(MetadataBuilder builder, MetadataReader _)
     at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TItem item, Func`3 read)
     at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.BuildMetadata(ModuleDefinition module, MetadataBuilder metadata)
     at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.Write(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModule(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.WriteAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, String directory, WriterParameters writerParameters)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.WriteAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, String directory, WriterParameters writerParameters)
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.OutputAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main(String[] args)
```

I tried to include the SkiaSharp.Views.Android Dll so that is not trimmed with this:

```
    <PropertyGroup>        
        <EnableTrimAnalyzer>true</EnableTrimAnalyzer>
        <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
        <TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

But it seems that didn't work.
I could disable trimming, but then I would have to disable AOT as well which I want to avoid.
[image]

Is there another way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: You may set the PublishTrimmed property to false. For more steps to publish a  MAUI Android app , you may refer to the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli. Also, may I know what AOT aswell means?

Comment: AOT is ahead of time compilling which improves startup time and performance. As mentioned before would I have to disable that aswell when I would want to disable trimming which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You don't need to disable that aswell at the same time.

Comment: On .net 7 RC2 I get this error message when I set `PublishTrimmed` to false: `The 'RunAOTCompilation' MSBuild property is only supported when trimming is enabled. Edit the project file in a text editor to set 'PublishTrimmed' to 'true' for this build configuration`

Comment: Native AOT applications come with a few fundamental limitations and compatibility issues. Some are related to trimming, you can refer to the documentation for details：https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/#limitations-of-native-aot-deployment. The error before you did not disable trimming was a linker related error, for the solution, you can refer to the link: https://github.com/dotnet/linker/issues/1559.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I can follow. I read through the GitHub Issue you linked and from what I understand they say it's a bug and that they have fixed it 2 years ago. Given that it works with .net 6 that makes sense. but why does it no longer work with .net 7?

Comment: This may still be a compatibility issue in nature, so could you consider switching back to .Net6 version if necessary?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue too in my app... also after updating my app to .NET 7. Any idea on why it doesn't work anymore? When will it work? As a workaround, adding this to my .csproj solved the problem for android

`<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
    <EnableTrimAnalyzer>False</EnableTrimAnalyzer>
    <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
  </PropertyGroup>`

But then, app is no longer optimized with this tags in .csproj so it's just a temporary fix...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not expert enough to explain the intricacies of the situation but here is a quick workaround (see comments to question above for more details).

Right click the project and select "Properties"

Find "Enable trimming" and uncheck it.
[image]

Then find AOT and uncheck it too
[image: 2]

To be clear, this may not be the best way to resolve it permanently since the app will be less optimized.

Comment: This should not be the solution only a temporary workaround I created a github issue with a reference sample which links to this post: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/2327

Comment: Just want to chime in to say this solved this exact error message, which is great for a first-timer who wants to just test the publication procedure.